# In Rust, how to make an vec of trait with self?

Tags: rust

Just wondering how to put **a trait with self** into a vec? I thought it should be a common question but I have never searched the answer...

Here is the code:

```rust
use tokio::time::{delay_for, Duration};

#[async_trait::async_trait]
trait Interface: Default + Sized {
    async fn update(&mut self) -> bool where Self: Sized;
}

struct Adder {
    pub state: i32,
}

impl Default for Adder {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { state: 0 }
    }
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Interface for Adder {
    async fn update(&mut self) -> bool {
        delay_for(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        self.state = self.state + 1;
        println!("Inc state to: {}", self.state);
        return true;
    }
}

struct Suber {
    pub state: i32,
}


impl Default for Suber {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { state: 0 }
    }
}


#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Interface for Suber {
    async fn update(&mut self) -> bool {
        delay_for(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        self.state = self.state - 1;
        println!("Dec state to: {}", self.state);
        return true;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let updaters: Vec<Box<dyn Interface>> = vec![Box::new(Adder::default()), Box::new(Suber::default())];
    for mut u in updaters {
        u.update();
    }
}
```

But I will get the error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Interface` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:51:19
   |
4  | trait Interface: Default + Sized {
   |       ---------  -------   ----- ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
   |       |          |
   |       |          ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
   |       this trait cannot be made into an object...
...
51 |     let updaters: Vec<Box<dyn Interface>> = vec![Box::new(Adder::default()), Box::new(Suber::default())];
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Interface` cannot be made into an object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because the trait `Interface` does not satisfy [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/items/traits.html?highlight=object,safety#object-safety).

> - It must not require `Self: Sized`
> - All associated functions must either have a `where Self: Sized` bound, or
>
>   - Not have any type parameters (although lifetime parameters are allowed), and
>   - Be a method that does not use `Self` except in the type of the receiver.
> - It must not have any associated constants.
> - All supertraits must also be object safe.

---

#### Update

You can change `trait Interface: Default + Sized` into `trait Interface` (because `Default` also requires `Sized`). But I don't know if that meets your need. @UkonnRa

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how to fix the code?

Comment: So I cannot use both `Default` and trait object together?

Comment: @UkonnRa You can not make your trait be `Sized` and invoke methods that require `Self: Sized` on a trait object. `Default` requires `Sized` so I think the answer is "No, you can not". But from your code, I don’t see where you need to use `Default` within this trait. Just remove `: Default + Sized` and `where Self: Sized` then your code can be compiled.